# Vue router view event propagation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I cant't figure out why the router-view does not emit the "login" event.
Here's the fiddle I'm playing with: https://jsfiddle.net/cvtwxf6h/22/

I want 2 different layouts, one for logged user and another for not logged user. The layout to display is determined by the `logged` property of the Index component.
When I click "Login" in the login page, a "login" event should propagate up to the Index component to update the `logged` property and change layout. For some reason the router-view does not emit the event, what am I doing wrong?

(I just want to understand the problem, I'm not interested in alternative ways to achieve this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `router-link` navigates to a different route (via `to="{name: 'index'}"`) *before* the `login` event is emitted, which causes the event to be lost somehow. If the target route is the same as the current route (no navigation), the event reaches the parent component without a problem.

A workaround would be to imperatively navigate with [`$router.push()`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-push) *after* emitting the event:

```
const LoginPage = {
  template: `<router-link to="" @click.native="switchToLoggedPage({ name: 'index' })">Login</router-link>`,
  methods: {
    switchToLoggedPage(route) {
      this.$emit('login');
      this.$router.push(route);
    },
  },
};
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/awo1bqd3/)

Comment: How would you handle dynamic routes? It seems you're hard-coding the route here

Comment: @TheRealChx101 The argument to `$router.push` accepts a `params` key that you would have to use for dynamic path parameters.  If you need additional help, I recommend posting a new question with details so that someone familiar with the topic can provide an answer. I'll chime in if I can.